# Solrcloud 4.4 set more then 1 update.chain request handler

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am using solrcloud 4.4 and i need to have 2 requestHandler.  I am new to solr.

I am using 3rd party plugins, and both require to add a line such as:

```
<str name="update.chain">something</str>
```

and then there will be a

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="something">
```

My problem is that both are required to be inside:

```
<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.XmlUpdateRequestHandler">
```

What is the proper way to have them both ? I read that i **can not** do:

```
<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.XmlUpdateRequestHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="update.chain">something</str>
<str name="update.chain">something1</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just create a chain that combines your processors in the order that makes sense. Make sure not to duplicate on the final LogUpdate and RunUpdate processors.

But be clear that you understand what the [different processors](http://www.solr-start.com/info/update-request-processors/) do and in which order.